# Slider misbehaving

Tags: css, wordpress

I've implemented a [slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shiftnav-responsive-mobile-menu/) plugin into my theme and unfortunately, some misbevahiour occurs when is activated using the golden info+ button.

The highlighted elements, is acting unusual:

-the left sidebar text and the lower right arrow, is changing its position going up or disappearing (depending on slider);

-the header logotext + menu, is jiggling at closing slider end position (I suppose that this has to do with an unwanted horrizontal scrolling bar that also appear at closing transition);
Live link [here](http://goo.gl/IU1SXV);

Is there any propper fix solutions for the above described tweaking the `css`? not so sure how to approach this.Thanks,

[image]

Comment: I believe your header "jiggling" on slider close has to do with this style: `.shiftnav-wrap { margin-top: -1px; }`. If you remove that it won't move on close.

Comment: it works like a charm, thank you very very much. honestly, looking for this workaround since a few good days now, trying to tweak the code ...

Comment: I think your sidebar text jumping has to do with this style: `.bar-side > div { margin-top:150px; }`. Try removing this... I know it won't be positioned how you want it, but at least we can determine this is the cause and try and figure out a better way to position.

Comment: not really still changing his position, this time is going down. Meanwhile, for the same issue, I've found this `.bar-side > div { position: relative; margin-top: 612px; }`  Not tested in every browsers but in Chrome it looks like it should. Can you please confirm? even in this way, is not staying fixed into the page... is moving slower than the slider when is opening and for a half of a second is covering it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out somehow

```
.shiftnav-wrap { 
  margin-top: -1px; /* thank you very much @zgood, logotext / menu is not jiggling anymore :) */
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* adding this line to hide the horizontal scrollbar that appear on slider closing phase */
}

#scroll_totop {
  top: 850px; /* instead of bottom: 25px to prevent disappearing */
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  .bar-side > div {
     position: relative; /* to keep in place the jiggling left sidebar */
     margin-top: 612px;
   }
}

.bar-side > div {
  position: relative; /* to keep in place the jiggling left sidebar */
}
```

Also, setting these `transition-delay: .0s` will make the slider translate in the same time with the `wrapper` and the sidebar text will remain uncovered by the slider in the opening phase.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .shiftnav-open .shiftnav-wrap {
        -webkit-transition-delay: .0s;
        -moz-transition-delay: .0s;
        -ms-transition-delay: .0s;
        -o-transition-delay: .0s;
        transition-delay: .0s
    }
}
```